# Singularities of moduli spaces $M_g$

Tags: riemann-surfaces, complex-manifolds, moduli-space, teichmueller-theory

This [survey](https://www.intlpress.com/site/pub/files/_fulltext/journals/iccm/2015/0003/0002/ICCM-2015-0003-0002-a005.pdf) paper from Lizhen Ji says:

> Teichmüller was aware that nontrivial automorphisms of Riemann surfaces caused difficulty in constructing $M_g$ and singularities of $M_g$, and he
>   introduced the idea of marking to rigidify Riemann surfaces and hence to kill nontrivial automorphisms of Riemann surfaces. This is the
>   meaning of topological determination.

I wonder what the singularities of $M_g$ mean? In my mind $M_1$ is biholomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$, does that mean there are no singularities of $M_g$? Are there any examples?

Comment: @CharlieFrohman how is that related to the Moduli problem?

Comment: @CharlieFrohman but how does that relate to the " nontrivial automorphisms of Riemann surfaces caused difficulty in constructing $M_g$" Is $M_g$ not a complex manifold when $g>1$? In my mind a a singular point means it makes the point failing to be smooth so that the variety can't be a manifold

Comment: Try this: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-727-topics-in-algebraic-geometry-intersection-theory-on-moduli-spaces-spring-2006/lecture-notes/const.pdf

Comment: Have you reached far enough in that survey (or in other literature) to know the distinction between Teichmuller space and moduli space? If you do then it would be possible to answer your question. But if you do not, then I suggest that's what you need to learn.